# Creating generic class in React component based on prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, immutable.js, typescript-generics

I'm working with `React` and `immutable.js`, and I need to use the `Record`-based type inside component, which have one of it's fields value as `keyof` some object.

This is the basic type definition:

```
import { Record } from 'immutable';

export const types = { // basic object holding possible values for Record
  date: 'date'
};

export interface IProp<T> { // interface for Record
  type: keyof T | '';
}

export type PropertyFactory<T extends typeof types> = typeof Property;
export function Property<T extends typeof types>(types: T) {
    return class CustomProperty extends Record<IProp<T>>({type: ''}) {};
}
```

In another place I'm referring to this type to get a derived one:

```
export const derivedTypes = Object.assign({}, types, {
  select: 'select'
});

export class DerivedProperty extends Property(derivedTypes) {}
```

Finally, I create the React element itself:

```
interface Props<T extends typeof types, P> {
  types: T;
  ctor: { new(js?: Partial<IProp<T>>): P };
}

class Element<T extends typeof types, P extends InstanceType<ReturnType<PropertyFactory<T>>>> extends React.Component<Props<T, P>> {
  constructor(props: Props<T, P>){ super(props) };
  create() {return new this.props.ctor()};
}

const test = <Element<typeof derivedTypes, DerivedProperty>
  types={derivedTypes}
  ctor={DerivedProperty}
/>
```

And it throws a compilation error:

```
Type 'DerivedProperty' does not satisfy the constraint 'Property<{ date: string; }>.CustomProperty'.
  Types of property 'toJSON' are incompatible.
    Type '() => IProp<{ date: string; } & { select: string; }>' is not assignable to type '() => IProp<{ date: string; }>'.
      Type 'IProp<{ date: string; } & { select: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'IProp<{ date: string; }>'.
        Type '{ date: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ date: string; } & { select: string; }'.
          Type '{ date: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ select: string; }'.
            Property 'select' is missing in type '{ date: string; }'.
```

I can't quite understand what's going wrong, but it does, whether with type inference for `Element` or with explicit generics. Maybe I'm on entirely wrong way?

---

**upd:** we're using the `immutable.js v4.0.0-rc.9`, *not* the stable version, with typings included.

Comment: I get an error on `Record<IProp<T>>({type: ''})`, `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1` what definitions for imutable do you have ?

Comment: Thanks, updated the question.